# SQL Server slower than data transfer

Tags: sql-server, networking, linked-server

I have two Windwos Server 2012 connected with 1Gbps switch. They are in blade and sharing same storage.

When I copy files between them I am geting the speed of 982Mbps. So that is great ;)

Also I have two SQL Server 2012 installed on those machines and those servers are linked to each other, with TCP, (not named pipes).

And connection between them is, slow. I have created one large table ~ 2GB without indexes ..

*I have tried with indexed table also, every query is ~ 3 times slower when linked server is involved. 
I have tried to execute bunch of small ones that only selects one row realy fast, and they are also 3 times slower.*

---

**No metter what I do, ethernet speed is always ~120Mbps**

And when I execute from SQL SERVER A:

```
select * into SQL_SERVER_A.NEWTABLE from  
SQL_SERVER_A.TABLE
```

It takes about 1min;

```
select * into SQL_SERVER_A.TABLE from LINKED_SERVER_SQLB.DATABASE.SCHEMA.TABLE
```

I need about 2:30

So my guess was, maybe HDD cannot optimaze how to read/write since it is on different server.

But when I execute also from SQL SERVER A, also about 2:30

```
select * into LINKED_SERVER_SQLB.SCHEMA.NEWTABLE from LINKED_SERVER_SQLB.DATABASE.SCHEMA.TABLE
```

So I am inserting into same database. But time is different. So my guess is it is network issue. Speed newer goes above 120Mbps.

I have tried tracert and I get other machine in one hoop.

Is this network issue?
How can I investigate further?

I have tried with OPENQUERY results are the same.

Execution plan:
[image]

Comment: 1) Distributed query 2) Linked servers use OLEDB driver (additional overhead). How about using bcp to dump data to file, move it and import back at second server?

Comment: It is not an option, because there is a bunch of T-SQL and .net code that should run on both servers.

Comment: So prepare for distributed query performance problems (especially joins between local and remote).